# Apply array of functions to a matrix

Tags: matlab, sorting, vectorization

I have a matrix `M` with rows sorted by one column (let's say `c`), *i.e*:

```
M = sortrows(M,c)
```

I need to apply a function to each row of the matrix, and this function depends on the value in the column `c` used for sorting. For example, if column `c` is the vector `[1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3]'`, I need to  call `f1` for rows 1 to 3, `f2` with rows 4 to 6 and `f3` with rows 7 to 11 as arguments.

Also, I want to call each function with all the rows that contain the same value in column `c` passed as an argument, to avoid using a loop on rows which is too slow. Is there a (very) fast way to do that? (if sorting `M` is not necessary it would be even better).

Thanks.

I precise my need with some code (M is not sorted here, as it seems not necessary):

```
function test  
M=zeros(4,2);  
c=2;  
M(1:2,2)=[3,6]';
M(3:5,2)=[1,3,1]';
M(6:10,2)=[3,6,1,6,3]';   

function res = f1(y1,y2)
res=[1,1,1];
end

function res = f3(y1,y2)
res=[2,2,2];
end

function res = f6(y1,y2)
res=[3,3,3];
end
```

We have:

```
M =

 0     3
 0     6
 0     1
 0     3
 0     1
 0     3
 0     6
 0     1
 0     6
 0     3
```

Now each row will be the argument of a function fi,i=1,...n with i=the value in column c, ie, with the example above:

f3 with rows 1,4,6,10 as arguments, f1 with rows 3,5,8 as arguments and f6 with rows 2,7 and 9 as arguments.

How can I do that without using loops ?

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to sort the rows of `M`. Try  [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) with a custom function:

```
F = {@f1, @f2, @f3}; %// Cell array of function handles
result = accumarray(repmat(M(:, c), size(M, 2), 1), M(:), [], @(x)F{x(1, c)}(x));
```

Note that `accumarray` converts groups of rows with the same `c` value to column vectors, so you'll have to reshape them back to, if your functions cannot handle this. For this, you can define an alternate set of functions before passing it to `accumarray`:

```
g = @(x)reshape(x, [], size(M, 2));
F = {@(x)f1(g(x)), @(x)f2(g(x)), @(x)f3(g(x))};
```

Comment: I'm not near MATLAB at the moment to test this, I hope I got the syntax right.

Comment: Thanks, but I get an error: ()-indexing must appear last in an index expression

Comment: I forgot to mention, the fi must return a vector, and not a scalar. Is it possible with accumarray ? P.S I could clone the function so that each clone returns each scalar element of the vector, but that would mean calling the function as many times as the length of the vector, which is slow.

Comment: @Gilbert Yes, I'll implement it this way when I have access to MATLAB.

Comment: @Gilbert Hi -- sorry for the delay -- I haven't had the time to resolve the issue yet -- I'll try to make time for later today. Is it okay with you?